# NOR gate circuit product

Tags: boolean-algebra

For the following figure:

[image: NOR gate circuit]

what is the ouput if 
a) both inputs are low
b) if one input is high and one low
c) does the circuit act like an OR or AND gate

I understand that the output for the first part of the circuit is 1 if both inputs are low only. I am confused about the connection between the first and second part of the circuit.

Comment: The second circuit just has the same input on both ports, that is, it is either both zero or both one.

Comment: The output of the first gate is connected to both inputs of the second gate. Where exactly is your confusion?

Comment: I just wanted to reaffirm that was the case @celtschk. So if the output is 1, then that is the input for both a and b in the next part of the circuit?

Comment: @julian: Exactly.

Comment: Hint: think of the first $NOR$ as an $OR$ followed by a $NOT$. Then $Y$ is $A\;OR\;B$ negated twice.

Answer (score 0):

By low, I assume you mean zero ?
A nor gate gives one when both inputs are zero & gives zero in the 3 other possible cases.
So the answer to a) is high & b)is low. The output from the first NOR gate will be $A$ NOR $B$, this will then be the inputs for both sides of the next NOR gate & so a formula for Y is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y = (A \ NOR\ B) \ NOR\ (A \ NOR\ B)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now make a truth table for this & you will be able to rapidly conclude that it is the same as an OR gate.